# Add Surpass Error Lint 'NewApi' except Using backward Compatibility in android Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, backwards-compatibility

I am working on action bar.I face a strange issue.My minimum sdk version is 8 and target is 15.I am using android-support-v4.jar. So that Action Bar will work on device lower than API 11.But i face error like [image]

I am not able to solve this problem. And most importantly i doubt on backward compatibility  of android, it will not work for sure in all version and hardware

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project ?

Comment: So many times but Error persist when i try to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

> My minimum sdk version is 8 and target is 15

Action BAr will not work on API's lower than Android 3.0 (API level 11) even with  android-support-v4.jar .

As a solution you can use action bar sherlock  for backward compatibility .

SITE: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

> The library will automatically use the native action bar when
>   appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around
>   your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an
>   action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.